# Use javascript to set image URL of image control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, image, imageurl

I have a Image, FileUpload and a Button controls. I want to save the image to the server from the local path obtained from FileUpload control. I implemented this functionality on Button Click in C#..

Now i want to set the image URL of Image control OnClientClick of the same button on which server side code is implemented.

Image URL will defer everytime depending on file selected in FileUpload control. Can anyone help me to understand how javascript can be used to set image URL based on thre file selected in File Upload Control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, understand that JavaScript doesn't understand, care, or even know about C# and its fancy "controls". It just deals with HTML. Period.  That said, you can use JavaScript's [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute) function to set the image URL of an `img` tag (not control). Like this:

```
document.getElementById('my-image').setAttribute('src', 'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41%2BjAZ4dUGL._SS500_.jpg');
```

Demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/je9Gx/

Comment: asp control's id changes when rendered so you cannot find then directly. that's why Jquery is easier approach to find them.

Comment: @Pranav, I'm not disagreeing that using jQuery is easier... that's why it exists in the first place, I'm just saying that you shouldn't make the assumption that the OP is using, or even wants to use, jQuery. If `getElementById` won't work, the OP can find another selector that _will_ work.  The essence of my answer, and the answer to his question, is the use of `setAttribute` (which I just noticed you implemented in your answer). _What_ he uses the function on, that's up to the OP. But yes, using jQuery would make it easier.

Comment: OP is asking about ASP image control not HTML image that is why i suggested to use jquery , because it is very difficult to find asp control through plain javascript; you have to write Regex to find the control in javascript  else one can use simple Jquery .

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to find the image control, where `imgid` is ID of image control;

```
$("[id$='imgid']").attr("src",pathfromfileuploader);

//pathfromfileuploader=it is a variable which stores the path taken from file uploader;
```

Hope it will help :)

Comment: You're assuming the OP is using jQuery.

Comment: @AymanSafadi: yes..it is easier approach to find asp controls and much faster.